# How to does a variable argument Functioncall as macro define?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, c99

Imagine, I have a debug source file,
which is like this:

```
#if _OWN_DEBUG_LEVEL != 0

    void DebugLogMsg (DebugStruct_t *DebugStruct, size_t sizeID, char const *szFormat, ...);

#else

    #define DebugLogMsg(_Expression1, _Expression2, _Expression3) ((void)0) 

#endif
```

In this case I do not really care about the additional arguments to the function, but what about this case?

```
#if _OWN_DEBUG_LEVEL > 0

    #undef DebugLogMsg1

    #define DebugLogMsg1(_Expression1, _Expression2, _Expression3) \ 
        DebugLogMsg(_Expression1, _Expression2, _Expression3)

#endif
```

In this case I'm not quite sure... when I call the macro like this:

```
DebugLogMsg1(pointer, var, pointer, 1, 2, 3);
```

will `_Expression3` be treat as would it be `pointer, 1, 2, 3` or what would be the exact behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just wouldn't work. You should use variadic macros:

```
#define DebugLogMsg1(a, b, c, ...) DebugLogMsg(a, b, c, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Or perhaps better (since it doesn't cause issues with trailing commas):

```
#define DebugLogMsg1(...) DebugLogMsg(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: But `__VA_ARGS__` isn't a c99 thing, is it?! Or do I jsut don't get your example?

Comment: @Zaibis: It's very much a C99 thing.

Comment: just opened my ISO/IEC 9899 and ctrl + f'ed for `__VA_ARGS__`, but I got no matches and never saw that before... and the syntax it self looks for me more like gnu99 attribute.

Comment: @Zaibis: Look again. 6.10.3.1/2.

Comment: You are right, I found it jsut right now by my self, the under scores of 6.10.3 5 are different, so I didn't get the match in my pdf ... Thanks dude.